# Find difference between two pandas Dataframes and and add all to new DF

Tags: python, pandas, concatenation

I have two `Guest-Lists`, in DataFrames,  and I want know which names dropped out, which ones were added, and then get a new DF, what do I do?

The two DFs are:

```
list1 = {'First Name': ['Adi', 'Beni', 'Dimi', 'Sergei'], 'Last Name': ['Beer', 'Wine', 'Liquor', 'Vodka'], 'Job': ['Brewer', 'Farmer', 'Shopowner', 'Guest']}

list2 = {'First Name': ['Adi', 'Beni', 'Sergei', 'Don'], 'Last Name': ['Beer', 'Wine', 'Vodka', 'Brown']}
```

If ``NameX is in `list1` and `list2`, create a new DataFrame with the the names that are in both.

If `NameX` was in `list1`, but dropped out in `list2`, show me in a new df.

And If `NameX` is only in `list2`, show me that in another df.

How do I do that?

By the way, it is intentional, that the 'Job' entry is only in one df. It is the goal to keep it in the new dfs.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to put the first and last names together, compare them and then separate them again.

Here is the corresponding code:

```
FIRST_NAME = 'First Name'
LAST_NAME = 'Last Name'
JOB = 'Job'
KEYS = [FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, JOB]


def intersection(lst1, lst2):
    return [value for value in lst1 if value in lst2]


def unzip(lst):
    a = []
    b = []
    for x, y in lst:
        a.append(x)
        b.append(y)
    return a, b


def get_jobs(dct, lst):
    return [dct.get(x) for x in lst]


def get_dict(lst, dict0, keys=KEYS):
    a, b = unzip(lst)
    values = [a, b, get_jobs(dict0, lst)]
    return dict(zip(keys, values))


list1 = {FIRST_NAME: ['Adi', 'Beni', 'Dimi', 'Sergei'], LAST_NAME: ['Beer', 'Wine', 'Liquor', 'Vodka'],
         JOB: ['Brewer', 'Farmer', 'Shopowner', 'Guest']}
list2 = {FIRST_NAME: ['Adi', 'Beni', 'Sergei', 'Don'], LAST_NAME: ['Beer', 'Wine', 'Vodka', 'Brown']}

mapped1 = list(zip(list1.get(FIRST_NAME), list1.get(LAST_NAME)))
mapped2 = list(zip(list2.get(FIRST_NAME), list2.get(LAST_NAME)))
dict_jobs = dict(zip(mapped1, list1.get(JOB)))

intersec = intersection(mapped1, mapped2)
left = []
right = []

for element in set(mapped1) ^ set(mapped2):
    left.append(element) if element in mapped1 else right.append(element)

dict_intersec = get_dict(intersec, dict_jobs)
dict_left = get_dict(left, dict_jobs)
dict_rigth = get_dict(right, dict_jobs)
```

Output:

```
{'First Name': ['Adi', 'Beni', 'Sergei'], 'Last Name': ['Beer', 'Wine', 'Vodka'], 'Job': ['Brewer', 'Farmer', 'Guest']}
{'First Name': ['Dimi'], 'Last Name': ['Liquor'], 'Job': ['Shopowner']}
{'First Name': ['Don'], 'Last Name': ['Brown'], 'Job': [None]}
```

In `dict_jobs` the merged names are mapped to their job.
`intersec` is the list containing the names contained in both original lists.
`left` contains the names that appear only in the first list, `right` only the names that appear in the second list.

Comment: +1. VERY good answer! No idea why no upvotes. I noticed you followed my Materials Modeling Stack Exchange proposal. We are now in the commitment stage and it would be very very helpful if you could click commit! https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/122958/materials-modeling?referrer=MGFkOGRlMTg1ODg2NTUxZDQ1MDVjZmQyOTg1ZDcxODQzMjc0OGIyMjBhZDM4ZDQ5MzM0MWE1YzZhNDBjMzhlYfHJBfp5EvPDPybryqjeDgXYucHU-wUv4jp4j6imjIfF0 Only 2.7% of the people fulfill commitment on new proposals anyway so it doesn't matter if you can't participate much, but it would be very very helpful if you can commit!

Answer (score 1):

`pandas.merge(...)` is what you are looking for:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html

To get all options at once just do:

```py
df1=pd.DataFrame(list1)
df2=pd.DataFrame(list2)

df3=pd.merge(df1, df2, on=["First Name", "Last Name"], how="outer", indicator=True)
```

Output:

```py
  First Name Last Name        Job      _merge
0        Adi      Beer     Brewer        both
1       Beni      Wine     Farmer        both
2       Dimi    Liquor  Shopowner   left_only
3     Sergei     Vodka      Guest        both
4        Don     Brown        NaN  right_only
```